# Eclipse preference - Multiple listener in radio buttons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

Here is the class which i use to create my custom preference page.

```
public class CustomPref extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

public CustomPref(){
    super(GRID);
}

@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
    addField(new RadioGroupFieldEditor("CHOICE",
            "An example of a multiple-choice preference", 1,
            new String[][] { { "&Choice 1", "choice1" },{ "&Choice 2", "choice2" }
                 }, getFieldEditorParent()));


}

@Override
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {

}


@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
    super.propertyChange(event);
    System.out.println(event.getNewValue());

}
```

}

But when i pressed "Choice 1" in log i see choice1.
when i pressed "Choice 2" in log i see choice1 and choice2.
when i pressed "Choice 1" again  in log i see choice2 and choice1.

It seems that radio button have a multiple event listener. Why event.getNewValue() called twice ?

Answer (score 0):

`RadioGroupFieldEditor` creates a number of `Button` controls with the radio style and adds a selection listener to each of the buttons.

When you click on one of the radio buttons a selection event is fired for the button which is no longer selected and another event for the button which has become selected. So you get two events - one for the deselection and one for the selection.